# What happen to state in Flink Task Manager when crash?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

may i know what happen to state stored in Flink Task Manager when this Task manager crash. Say the state storage is rocksdb, would those data transfer to other running Task Manager so that complete state data is ready for data processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink does not (yet) support dynamic rescaling of state, so the failed task manager must be recovered, and the job will be restarted from a checkpoint.

Exactly what that involves depends on how your cluster is configured, and whether the job failed because of an exception or because the machine/container running the task manager failed.

If you are using RocksDB and local recovery is enabled, then if the job died because of an exception, the task managers will all be able to restart the job more-or-less immediately from their local copy of the state. On the other hand, if a new task manager has to be spun up, then once it is running it will fetch what it needs from the latest checkpoint (from whatever distributed file system is used) and then the job will resume.

Without local recovery, every task manager will have to fetch the relevant portions of the checkpoint from the DFS.

In some cases it is possible to do something less expensive than a full recovery. See [fine-grained recovery](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4256) for details.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation @David. In case of crashed TM machine, I would like to know will the other TM take over the crashed TM's state to ensure data completion(say the state BYKEY, different key state will be stored in different TM) OR the crashed TM must be recovered to continue?

Comment: For example, 5 records,
rec1:KEYA;
rec2:KEYB;
rec3:KEYA;
rec4:KEYC;
rec5:KEYB;
,
TM1 stored state for rec1:KEYA, rec3:KEYA\n
TM2 stored state for rec2:KEYB, rec5:KEYB\n
TM3 stored state for rec4:KEYC\n

In case TM2 crashed, rec2 and rec5 will be assigned to other TM? Or those record only recover when TM2 being recover?

Also, those data before the checkpoint will loss in case of TM machine crash? Thanks.

Comment: The crashed TM must be recovered, and state updates since the last checkpoint will be lost. Of course that lost state should be recreated as the job rewinds and resumes.

Comment: thank you @David. A side question, am i right to say that if one of the TM crashed, the whole cluster need to be restart to get all states redistribute properly to continue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251385/flink-should-the-entire-cluster-be-restarted-if-a-single-task-manager-crashes